# Error in connecting MongoDB on Amazon EC2 using pymongo

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to use MongoDB on Amazon EC2 using Python3.4.3. 
I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653938/remotely-connecting-to-mongodb-http-interface-on-ec2-server): modified security groups setting and edited "/etc/mongod.conf" (comment out bind_id). However, when I run following code, I got this error:

```
ServerSelectionTimeoutError: SSL handshake failed: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

What else should I do?

The code I run is:

```
import pymongo
import ssl
client = pymongo.MongoClient('ec2-**-**-*-**.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com', 27017, 
ssl=True, ssl_keyfile='/Users/S/FILENAME.pem')

db = client["test"]
db.artist
collection = db.artist

import gzip
import json
from io import StringIO

with gzip.open('artist.json.gz', "rt") as a_file: 
    count=0
    bulk = []
    for line in a_file:
        jdata = json.load(StringIO(line)) 

        bulk.append(jdata) 
        count += 1

        if 1000 < count:
            print ('bulk insert!')

            collection.insert_many(bulk)
            bulk = []
            count = 0

    if len(bulk) > 0:
        collection.insert_many(bulk)
```

Comment: Facing the same issue. Were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: @Shivendra not yet. still looking for the solution.

Comment: I found something that worked for me.
Check that out. Hope that works for you too. 
[My question-answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35220123/1641628)