# pymongo - Unable to connect to mongodb running on EC2

Tags: python, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pymongo

I am connecting to a mongodb server on EC2. The mongo collections require authentication to connect.

I tried everything but I am getting the following error and can't seem to correct it.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

mongo_username = "username"
mongo_password = "password"
ssh_user = "user"
ssh_address = "ec2-**********.amazonaws.com"
ssh_port = 22
private_key = "path/to/key/mykey.pem"

def connect_to_mongo():
   try:
        client = MongoClient("mongodb://"+mongo_username+":"+mongo_password+"@" + ssh_address, ssl = True, ssl_keyfile = private_key)
        db = client.myDB

        #Should 'admin' be there or 'myDB'? 'admin' at least get if(auth) passed, while 'myDB' doesn't 
        auth = client.admin.authenticate(mongo_username,mongo_password) 

        if(auth):
                print "MongoDB connection successful"
                col = db.myCollection.count()
        else:
                print "MongoDB authentication failure: Please check the username or password"

        client.close()

   except Exception as e:
        print "MongoDB connection failure: Please check the connection details"
        print e

if __name__ == "__main__":
    connect_to_mongo()
```

**Output :**

```
MongoDB connection successful
MongoDB connection failure: Please check the connection details
SSL handshake failed: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried all the options and finally this worked.

```
client = MongoClient("mongodb://" + ssh_address+":27017") # No private key passing 
auth = client.myDB.authenticate(mongo_username,mongo_password) # Authenticate to myDB and not admin
db = client.myDB
```

So basically I don't need to pass a private key (which is required when doing ssh over to the EC2) since the port was already opened for all incoming IPs ( I guess this was an important fact that I should have known and posted in the question).

Also I was trying to authenticate via the `admin DB`, which I shouldn't have done because I was given access to `myDB` only.

Answer (score 2):

EC2 will close 27017 port by default. Create the in-bound rule as described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#creating-security-group) and [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/platforms/amazon-ec2/#secure-instances).

Comment: One of my co developers is accessing the mongodb through a Java interface and he is able to do it.
Do you still think this could be the reason?

Comment: Is this java instance running under same VPC? and are you accessing from outside of your EC2's VPC?

Comment: I don't know the answer to first question but I am accessing the EC2 from my home network.

Comment: amazon inter-connects all the EC2 instances launched in the same VPC by default, so if your friend is accessing the mongodb from the instance running from the same VPC, he would be able to connect. If you are accessing from your home, it's likely that your home network is not allowed as inbound. Anyways, your answer stays in the security group.

Comment: I think we have only one EC2 instance up. I think I will have to read up more on the things you mentioned otherwise I will keep on asking dumb questions.