# Amazon EC2 unable to connect to MongoDB via client mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

I am unable to connect to remote MongoDB from my local Machine. Getting the below exceptions while trying to connect using Mongo shell.

Request from shell:

mongo --username[username] --password[password]--host [Public DNS] --port 27017

Response:
Failed to connect to :27017, reason: errno:61 Connection refused
2015-12-03T16:31:51.514-0500 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server , connection attempt failed
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181

I have followed the below template to configure the server on the Amazon cloud.
https://s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-reference/mongodb/latest/doc/MongoDB_on_the_AWS_Cloud.pdf

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does the security group attached to the MongoDB server have port 27017 open for the IP address you are trying to connect from?

Comment: @mbaird  Yes. I have opened this port in the security group.

Comment: netstat -a gives the following result on Mongodb server                             'tcp        0      0 *:51335                     *:*                         LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 *:27017                     *:*                         LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 *:sunrpc                    *:*                         LISTEN      
'

Comment: Is your `bind_ip` setting in /etc/mongod.conf uncommented? Try looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653938/remotely-connecting-to-mongodb-http-interface-on-ec2-server

Comment: mbaird, Yup, it 's uncommented and I have tried changing the bind_ip with different options. like port = 27017
  bind_ip = 127.0.0.1,[Mongo_node_Private_ip],[Public_ip]

Comment: You need to comment it out

Comment: Read all the answers in the post I linked.

Comment: @mbaird,I have modified the /etc/monogod.conf file and restarted the mongod server.But It is still showing the same error when I am trying to connect from client Mongo shell.